# How to add my ajax data to bootstrap4 cards

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

This is my part of html(ejs) file and I have multiple card forms(such as ID =myContent1, myContent2, myContetn3 ...) they receive ajax data when the i class=icon... is toggled. when the function(toggle) is activated, received ajax data mapping with myContent No. (ex. received ajax data ID 1 with myContent1 and 2 for myContent2 ... so on).

What I want to do is that, ajax data should be loaded when my html file is executed and automatically mapping with my card forms(based on card Id no)

need your kind help.

```
   <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header" id="cardHeader3" style="visibility: hidden;">unSaved</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <i class="icon-plus icons font-2xl" id="icon3" style="font-size: 5rem !important;margin-left: 46%;cursor:pointer;" onclick="toggler('myContent_3');"></i>
            <div id="myContent_3" class="card-title" style="display: none;">
              <form action="" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="input-group-text">sequence</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" id="notiSeq_3" name="notiSeq" class="form-control" value="">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text">
                      <i class="fa fa-sort-numeric-asc"></i>
                    </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="input-group-text">title</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" id="title_3" name="title" class="form-control" value="">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text">
                      <i class="fa fa-tumblr"></i>
                    </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="input-group-text">Link</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" id="link_3" name="link" class="form-control" value="">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text">
                      <i class="fa fa-hand-o-left"></i>
                    </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="input-group-text">exposureTime</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" id="notiTime_3" name="notiTime" class="form-control" value="" readonly style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text">
                      <i class="cui-calendar"></i>
                    </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                      <span class="input-group-text">Urgency</span>
                    </div>
                    <select class="form-control" id="viewYn_3" defaultValue="N">
                      <option value="N">N</option>
                      <option value="Y">Y</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text">
                      <i class="icon-eye icons"></i>
                    </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-actions">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick ="save('3')">Save</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="del('3')">Delete</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

And This is my part of js file. it currently works with when the card forms are toggled.

```
function toggler(divId) {
   var tempId = divId.slice(-1);
   var x = document.getElementById("icon" + tempId);
   var y = document.getElementById("cardHeader" + tempId);

  $.ajax({
    url: GW_URL+'/myRestAPI/get/'+tempId,
    type:'get',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType : "json",
    cache: false,
    success : function(data){
        $("#notiSeq_" + tempId).val(data.exposureNo);
        $("#title_" + tempId).val(data.title);
        $("#link_" + tempId).val(data.link);
        $("#notiTime_" + tempId).val(data.exposureTime + " - " + data.exposureTime2);
        $("#viewYn_" + tempId).val(data.urgency);

    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain what is not working?